Cannot ping pi, unless pi is actively pinging something else
Reloaded raspbian again and things seem to work. :)
Pi 3b+. Just reloaded rasbian with the newest version and now I am unable to ping the pi or SSH into it.
I have three other windows computers that I have tried from, each can ping the router, and other computers, but not the pi.
The pi on the other hand can ping everything on the network.
Fun part, if the pi is pinging another entity on the network, I CAN successfully ping the pi from any of the computers.
So, when the pi is actively pinging, it can be pinged.
What could be the reason I cannot ping the pi? I have checked and the pi is not blocked from the router. I think there must be a setting on the PI that is causing this?
Thanks

You've made no alterations after installing the OS? Which OS did you install, i.e. 32bit or 64bit? (I assume it is bookworm) Can you SSH when the pi is pinging? How long after you stop pinging from the pi does it take until you can't ping the pi? Can the pi reach the internet? if you ping a public IP (8.8.8.8 for example) does that make a difference?
